# Changing the name of Hadoop job?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Hi I would like to change the name of the running Hadoop Job to a meaningful name.
Is there any command to change the name of running job, just like this -

`hadoop job -set-priority <JOB_ID> 'HIGH';` which changes the priority of the job

Comment: do you really want to change the name of a _running_ job? I don't think that's possible once you've submitted the job.

Answer (score 0):

The job id is assigned by the job tracker on submit, by calling [`JobTracker.getNewJobId()`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common/blob/branch-0.20/src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobTracker.java). It cannot be pre-set. To change the the job priority, you must retrieve the ID from submission. Read comments on [PIG-948](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-948) why is not always possible to know the MR job id from PIG:

> Reason for that is JobControlCompiler compiles a set of
>   inter-dependent MR jobs and generates a job-control object which is
>   then submitted asynchronously to hadoop for execution. Since we dont
>   block on those thread, its possible that **job-ids are not yet assigned
>   when we ask for them**